# Android Jetpack Compose- Sticky UI vertical scrolling

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-nestedscrollview

I want to develop something which is mentioned in below link:
[Sticky header similar like IOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgc6a.gif)

I have checked the nested scrolling from [google nested scrolling](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/gestures) but its not giving the exact behaviour. Any suggestions or links for the same

I am able to implement the nested scrolling to sticky tabs but am facing issue while scrolling the Bitcoin Cash text in the header, it  is not coming on the title of top nav bar.

I thought to show the title when scrolling up to maxheight and hide when scrolling down. But how to acquire this logic. Please suggest